# How do I scroll when using a vnc client on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, vnc, ios

I have an iPhone with Veency (via Cydia) on it. I can connect to it on my mac through a VNC, but I can't seem to scroll down on the iOS screen from the mac. Is there a trick to this?

Comment: In the demonstration video on [the veency site](http://cydia.saurik.com/info/veency/) shows them scrolling by left clicking and dragging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling through a VNC or emulation program doesn't work like you'd assume. Because iOS recognizes `touch` events, you have to actually click your mouse on the VNC window and drag, as if you were touching the screen with your finger.